# Webpack for Django Project on Docker (Production)

Tags: django, docker, webpack, minify, bundling-and-minification

I have a Django project, and I've successfully installed and run **Webback** with the purpose of minifying frontend files (CSS, JS, HTML) using **npm** (and creating `config.js`) - I want to make **Docker** do this job automatically from the **production server side**.

I tried to do it from the backend through **Django settings** (`STATIC_FILE`), but failed.

```
var config = {
    module: {},
};

var src = '/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/';

var File1JS = Object.assign({}, config, {
  entry: src + 'static/assets/js/file1.js', /// Source File
  output:{
    filename:'file1.js',
    path: src + 'static/assets/js' /// Ourput File (Minified File)
  }
});
var File2JS = Object.assign({}, config,{
  entry: src + 'static/assets/js/file2.js',
  output:{
    filename:'file2.js',
    path: src + 'static/assets/js'
  }
});

module.exports = {
  File1JS, File2JS
};
```

Any advice or help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running webpack at your production server sounds like not the best idea. The most straightforward approach is to build your frontend code during continuous integration (CI) & just put the output files where ever you need them.

Having webpack on your production server would be a necessity if your application accepts js uploads from users & then run it on the server. This setup would have so many security concerns - for attacks to your server, to abusing your resources.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just came with an idea, to create two directories in the ``static/assets``, one ``min`` the other ``unminify``, and every time we want to push to the production or GitHub we can use the Webpack command link locally to minify the files. What do you think about this approach?

Comment: You mean doing it from dev machine? This will work, and at some point you will be able to upgrade it to have CI do the building.